# How to use button to execute a action stored in java class?

Tags: java, android, button, client, server

So, I previously asked about my project and a kind guy gave me the key words.
Now that I'm working on it, I would like to know if its possible to:

Get the java class (Client) action stored in a java class, and calling it to the button something like:

```
    Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);

    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(Client);
```

Sorry, I'm just a guy who is trying to do his school project, and I have no android formation on my school so go easy on me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in order for you to complete this project you will have to research Threads (start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)) and Handlers ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)). The startActivity method is used to start a different activity than the one the user is on (that is, open a new "screen" for the user with a new layout, I don't think that this is what you want or need to do). Also, the startActivity method accepts an Intent object and not a general class like your Client class.
If you are going to perform long operations on your main thread (the one that the user is currently interacting with), you should do it in a seperate Thread
This is how your MainActivity should look like, it is partial, there are more efficiant ways to do it and there are other solutions such as AsyncTask and Services but this should give you a general idea:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Handler mHandler;
    Thread myThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    //your code for what do do with the information coming
                    //from your background thread
                }

                }
                myThread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
                myThread.start();

            }                
        };


    }


    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            Client client = new Client();
            client.   //whatever methods and operations you want to run through
                      //your Client object

            //create a Message object to pass so it is handled by
            //your main thread (presenting retrieved data to the user 
            //for example)
            Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();

            //when you want to send a Message object back to main
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i did a small thing this time

public class MainActivity{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OtherClass.OtherMethod();

    }
}
This will allow me to get the other class running, but what im still confused is where it is the button, can you help me?

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to add your button in the answer, I just edited it, hope this helps :)

Comment: Ty hehe ^^ you helped